# JavaFX and Generics

Tags: generics, javafx

I am just starting to look at JavaFX and it seems like a nice language -- reminds me of Scala without the sophisticated (complex) type system.

Is there any word on when generics will be added? I hate going back to "Java 1.4" style coding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never. It was announced just yesterday at JavaOne that the JavaFXScript programming language (that's what you are talking about, right?) will be abandoned. Only the JavaFX framework will be continued, in order to be used with other JVM languages such as Scala, Ruby, Python, Clojure or Java.

Comment: I JUST bought the Manning book last week :-(.